# Ошибка в логике рисования линий js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Прямые не проходят через узел(точку 0 0). На этой странице я ищу корни системы Д.У. С постоянными коэффициентами. Предполагаю что линии будут проходить через центр и всегда существовать. Проверяю вещественные корни (лямбда) одного знака. Пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку.

[image: Проблема]

```js
function calculate(a, b, c, d) {
  t1.value = "Нажмите кнопку, чтобы посчитать.";
  var xr = 0,
    xi = 0,
    yr = 0,
    yi = 0,
    state = -1;
  var c1 = 1,
    c2 = -a - d;
  c3 = a * d - b * c;
  t2.value = "x^2+" + c2 + "x+" + c3;
  var D = c2 * c2 - 4 * c1 * c3;
  t3.value = "Дискриминант =" + D;
  if (D > 0) {
    state = 1;
    xr = (-c2 - Math.sqrt(D)) / 2 / c1;
    yr = (-c2 + Math.sqrt(D)) / 2 / c1;

  } else if (D == 0) {
    state = 2;
    xr = -c2 / 2 / c1;
    yr = xr;

  } else if (D < 0) {
    state = 3;
    xr = -c2 / 2 / a;
    xi = -Math.sqrt(-D) / 2 / c1;
    yr = -c2 / 2 / c1;
    yi = Math.sqrt(-D) / 2 / c1;

  }
  t4.value = " x=" + xr.toFixed(4);
  if (state == 3) {
    t4.value += " " + xi.toFixed(4) + "i";
  }

  if (state != 2) {
    t4.value += "  x=" + yr.toFixed(4);
    if (state == 3) {
      t4.value += " " + yi.toFixed(4) + "i";
    }
  }
  if (state == 1) {
    if (xr < 0 && yr < 0) {
      t5.value = "Корни вещественные и одного знака. Узел устойчивый.";
    } else if (xr < 0 && yr > 0) {
      t5.value = "Корни вещественные и разных знаков. Седло.";
    } else if (xr > 0 && yr > 0) {
      t5.value = "Корни вещественные и одного знака. Узел неустойчивый.";
    }
  }
  if (state == 2) {
    if (xr != 0) {
      t5.value = "Корни вещественные, одинаковые. Вырожденный узел.";
    } else {
      t5.value = "Корни равны нулю. Параллельные линии."
    }
  }
  if (state == 3) {
    if (xr > 0) {
      t5.value = "Вещественная часть больше нуля. Неустойчивый фокус.";
    } else if (xr < 0) {
      t5.value = "Вещественная часть меньше нуля. Устойчивый фокус.";
    } else if (xr == 0) {
      t5.value = "Вещественная часть равна нулю. Центр.";
    }
  }
  t6.value = state;
  var vx1, vx2, vy1, vy2
  if (state != 3) {

    var a2 = a - xr,
      b2 = b;
    if (a2 < 0) a2 = -a2;
    if (b2 < 0) b2 = -b2;
    while (a2 != b2) {
      if (a2 > b2)
        a2 = a2 - b2;
      else b2 = b2 - a2;
    }
    vx1 = (a - xr) / b2;
    vy1 = b / b2;
    t7.value = vx1 + " вектор";
    t8.value = vy1;

    var a2 = d - yr,
      b2 = c;
    if (a2 < 0) a2 = -a2;
    if (b2 < 0) b2 = -b2;
    while (a2 != b2) {
      if (a2 > b2)
        a2 = a2 - b2;
      else b2 = b2 - a2;
    }
    vx2 = c / b2;
    vy2 = (d - yr) / b2;
    t9.value = vx2 + " вектор";
    t10.value = vy2;
  }


  var canva = document.getElementById("CANV");
  var cont = canva.getContext("2d");
  cont.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
  var limC1 = 1,
    limC2 = 1;
  for (C1 = -limC1; C1 < limC1; C1++) {
    for (C2 = -limC2; C2 < limC2; C2++) {
      if (C1 == 0 && C2 == 0) break;
      var step = 0.1;
      for (t = -10; t < 10; t += step) {
        cont.beginPath()
        var shx = 300,
          shy = 300,
          zx = 10,
          zy = 10;
        cont.moveTo(zx * C1 * vx1 * Math.exp(xr * t) + shx, zy * C2 * vx2 * Math.exp(yr * t) + shy);
        cont.lineTo(zx * C1 * vy1 * Math.exp(xr * (t + step)) + shx, zy * C2 * vy2 * Math.exp(yr * (t + step)) + shy);
        cont.stroke();
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<html>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <head>
    <title>
      No title
    </title>
    <script src="Calc.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="a" type='number' value="0" step="0.0001">
    <input id="b" type='number' value="0" step="0.0001">
    <input type="button" onclick="calculate(parseFloat(a.value),parseFloat(b.value),parseFloat(c.value),parseFloat(d.value))" value="Посчитать"/></br>
    <input id="c" type='number' value="0" step="0.0001">
    <input id="d" type='number' value="0" step="0.0001">
    <output id="t1" type="">Нажмите кнопку, чтобы посчитать</output></br>
    <output id="t2" type=""></output></br>
    <output id="t3" type=""></output></br>
    <output id="t4" type=""></output></br>
    <output id="t5" type=""></output></br>
    <output id="t6" type=""></output></br></br>

    <output id="t7" type=""></output></br>
    <output id="t8" type=""></output></br></br>
    <output id="t9" type=""></output></br>
    <output id="t10" type=""></output></br> 
    
    <canvas id="CANV" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Проблема решена. Неправильно считались лини. Верный вариант:  `cont.moveTo(zx*C1*vx1*Math.exp(xr*t)+zx*C2*vx2*Math.exp(yr*t)     +shx,zx*C1*vy1*Math.exp(xr*(t))+shx,zy*C2*vy2*Math.exp(yr*(t))+shy);
      cont.lineTo(zx*C1*vx1*Math.exp(xr*(t+step))+zx*C2*vx2*Math.exp(yr*(t+step))     +shx,zx*C1*vy1*Math.exp(xr*(t+step))+shx,zy*C2*vy2*Math.exp(yr*(t+step))+shy);`

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите ваш комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ из комментария:

---

Проблема решена. Неправильно считались лини. Верный вариант:

```
cont.moveTo(zx*C1*vx1*Math.exp(xr*t)+zx*C2*vx2*Math.exp(yr*t) +shx,zx*C1*vy1*Math.exp(xr*(t))+shx,zy*C2*vy2*Math.exp(yr*(t))+shy);
cont.lineTo(zx*C1*vx1*Math.exp(xr*(t+step))+zx*C2*vx2*Math.exp(yr*(t+step)) +shx,zx*C1*vy1*Math.exp(xr*(t+step))+shx,zy*C2*vy2*Math.exp(yr*(t+step))+shy);
```